# From $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^p}\;$ to $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f'(x)}{px^{p-1}}\;?$

Tags: real-analysis

Define $f: (0 , +\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$  differentiable satisfying $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^p} = 1$ **and $f'$ is monotonically increasing.**

Can we conclude $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f'(x)}{px^{p-1}}=1$?

*My try:*

Attempt 1：(try to use Lagrange Mean Value Theorem)

> Considering $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{x^{p-1}} $，where $f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(\zeta)$ , $x<\zeta<x+1$
>   \begin{align}
>  \frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{x^{p-1}}
>   &=\frac{f(x+1)}{(x+1)^p}\frac{(x+1)^p}{x^p}x-\frac{f(x)}{x^p}x
> \\&=\frac{f(x+1)}{(x+1)^p}\frac{x^{p+1}+px^p+\mathbb{o}(x^p)}{x^p}-\frac{f(x)}{x^p}x
> \\&=\frac{f(x+1)}{(x+1)^p}(x+p+\mathbb{o}\left(1\right))-\frac{f(x)}{x^p}x
> \\&=p\frac{f(x+1)}{(x+1)^p}+x(\frac{f(x+1)}{(x+1)^p}-\frac{f(x)}{x^p})+\mathbb{o}\left(1\right)
> \end{align}
>   Because $f'$ is monotonically increasing we just need to prove $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{x^{p-1}}=p $ then we can arrive at $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f'(x)}{px^{p-1}}=1$
>
> So I aimed to prove $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} x(\frac{f(x+1)}{(x+1)^p}-\frac{f(x)}{x^p})=0$.
>
> But I failed and didn't know how to move on...

Attempt 2：(try to use Cauchy Mean Value Theorem)

> Considering $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{(x+1)^p-x^p} $, where $\dfrac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{(x+1)^p-x^p}=\dfrac{f'(\xi)}{p \xi^{p-1}}$ , $x<\xi<x+1$
>
> Similarly , because $f'$ is monotonically increasing we just need to prove $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{(x+1)^p-x^p} =1 $ then we can arrive at $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f'(x)}{px^{p-1}}=1$
>
> Actually I found it equivalent to proving that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{x^{p-1}}=p $  $\ldots$

Any hints ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any assumptions about $p$? Can it be negative, or must it be positive?

Comment: @coffeemath I thought both should be considered , and I think $0＜p＜1$ is impossible because of the condition

Comment: It seems that $x^p (\frac{f(x＋1)}{(x＋1)^p}-\frac{f(x)}{x^p}) \, \to 0 $ when $x \to ＋\infty$ is easier to prove (the situation $p＞1$)

Comment: Here is nice proof https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4841591/reverse-lhospital-rule-under-certain-conditions