# Reverse L'Hospital rule under certain conditions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, derivatives

Let $p$ be a positive real number, and $f:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function. Suppose that $f'(x)$ is monotonically increasing. Show that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^p}=l$ if and only if $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{px^{p-1}}=l$.

The direction "$\Leftarrow$" follows from L'Hospital rule. By the way, many textbooks only prove the L'Hopsital rule for $\frac{0}{0}$ case, but just say that the proof for $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ case is similar. I do not think that the proof for $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ case is as easy as that for $\frac{0}{0}$ case. Come back to our question, how to prove "$\Rightarrow$"?

Comment: Have you tried using the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem on $[N,x]$ for large $N$?

Comment: @TedShifrin By Cauchy Mean Value Theorem, we are only able to prove "$\Leftarrow$", right?

Comment: No, I believe that by dragging $N$ to infinity, you get a sequence of points $c_N\to\infty$ with the desired limit. Then the fact that $f’$ is  increasing should give the limit. But perhaps I’m wrong.

Comment: @TedShifrin I understand your thought, but could you please show the detailed proof? I think that with the process, we shall still meet with difficulties.

Comment: I didn't have a detailed proof in mind. Offhand, my thinking seems to be wrong. Now I'm not even sure your result is correct. Where did you find this?

Comment: @TedShifrin The question appeared in the past examination paper in my university. If the result is incorrect, is there any counter-example?

Comment: It may be useful to observe that $f'(x)$, under your conditions, is *continuous* in $\mathbb R^+$.  Also, the assertion is certainly true for $p=1$, since monotonicity implies that $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f'(x)$ exists either finite or infinite. But then de L'Hopital Theorem guarantees that this limit is equal to $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)/x$.

Comment: @dfnu How do you observe that $f'(x)$ is continuous?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044938/monotonic-function-limits-from-the-right-and-from-the-left, plus the fact that right and left limit must be equal at each point, for otherwise the function would not be differentiable at that point, by definition.

Comment: @dfnu Since $f'(x)$ is monotonically increasing, for any $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^+$, both $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0^+}f'(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0^-}f'(x)$ exist. But $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0^+}f'(x)$ or $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0^-}f'(x)$ may not equal $f'(x_0)$; or, could you prove this?

Comment: It is well known and not hard to prove using the mean value theorem that any derivative has the Darboux property so it cannot have discontinuities of the first order - in particular if it is monotonic or (locally) of bounded variation, it is continuous

Comment: @Conrad I just looked up Darboux property / theorem, and now the continuity of $f'(x)$ is fixed now. Thank you. Then what is the next step to prove the original question?

Comment: @dfnu If $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f'(x)=0$, can $p$ be less than $1$?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I'll delete my previous comment, in order not to generate any confusion.

Comment: note that here I assume $l$ can be anything as per L'Hopital - in other words, $0, \infty, -\infty$ etc; note that $f$ is also monotonic (at least from some $x_0$ on which doesn't matter for the purposes here) and $f,f'$ have constant signs again from some point on; so, in particular, one can have arbitrary $p>0$ though of course $l$ will be finite nonzero for at most one such

Comment: A few years ago somone asked the same question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3056530/from-lim-x-to-infty-fracfxxp-to-lim-x-to-infty-fracfx) but got no answer.

Comment: I have found a proof. Now I am busy, but I will write an answer with my proof as soon as possible. I think OP’s statement is true even if there is any differentiable function $g(x)$, instead of $x^p$, such that $g’(x)$ is monotonically increasing.

Comment: Did you solve this problem, in the meantime? Can I ask you a reference to the examination paper you took this question from?

Answer (score 2):

The assertion is true and it is an immediate consequence of the so called Monotone Density Theorem (see e.g. [here](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511721434), Theorem 1.7.2, p. 39).

We say that $\ell(x)$ is a *slowly varying function*, if $\ell$ is positive, measurable, and such that
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\ell(\lambda x)}{\ell (x)} = 1$$
for $\lambda > 0$.

Then we can state the following.

> **Monotone Density Theorem**. Let $U(x) = \int_0^x u(y) dy$. If $U(x) \sim c x^{\rho} \ell (x)$ ($x \to \infty$), where $c\ \in \mathbb R$ and $\ell (x)$ is a slowly varying function, and if $u(x)$ is ultimately monotone, then
> $$u(x) \sim c\rho x^{\rho-1} \ell(x)\ \ \ (x\to \infty)$$

The proof of the above theorem can be specialized in your case as follows.

We  can first write
$$f(bx)-f(ax)=\int_{ax}^{bx} f'(t) dt,$$
for $0<a < b$. Monotonicity of $f'$ yields
$$\frac{x(b-a)f'(ax)}{x^p}\leq \frac{f(bx)-f(bx)}{x^p}\leq \frac{x(b-a)f'(bx)}{x^p}. $$
The middle term is
$$\frac{f(bx)}{(bx)^p}b^p-\frac{f(ax)}{(ax)^p} a^p\to b^p-a^p,$$
for $x\to \infty$, due to the hypothesis $f\sim x^p$.

Letting $a=1$ in the first inequality above gives
$$\limsup_{x\to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{x^{p-1}} \leq \frac{b^p-1}{b-1}.$$
Taking $b\to 1^+$ leads therefore to
$$\limsup_{x\to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{x^{p-1}} \leq p.$$

Now let $b=1$ and $a\to 1^-$ in the second inequality to get
$$\liminf_{x\to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{x^{p-1}} \geq p,$$
and the thesis follows.

Answer (score 0):

I think a very health approach to such execises it to try and estimate the function directly using the definition of limit and some inequalities. Its not that common (as far as I saw in calculus books) but I like it and it seem to work, and in my opinion give a very good intuition to what's going on.

For every $\varepsilon>0$ we can find $M$ such that for every $x>M$ we have $$ (l-\varepsilon)px^{p-1} \le f'(x) \le (l+\varepsilon)px^{p-1} $$

Thus, we can infer (for example, by integrating, but also as a conclusion of Lagrange\Cauchy Intermediate Value Theorem) that

$$ (l-\varepsilon)(x^p-M^p)\le f(x)-f(M)\le (l+\varepsilon)(x^p-M^p)$$

rearranging gives

$$ \frac{f(M)+(l-\varepsilon)(x^p-M^p)}{x^p}\le \frac{f(x)}{x^p}\le\frac{f(M)+(l+\varepsilon)(x^p-M^p)}{x^p}$$

Taking $x$ to infinity gives

$$ l-\varepsilon\le\liminf_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^p}\le\limsup _{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^p}\le l+\varepsilon$$

since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we can infer that $\liminf_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^p}=\limsup_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^p}=l$, and thus the limit exists and equal to $l$.

Edit:

I apologize for the confusion, I proved the wrong direction :).

For the other direction, for every $\varepsilon>0$ we can find $M$ such that for every $x>M$ we have

$$ (l-\varepsilon)x^{p} \le f(x) \le (l+\varepsilon)x^{p} $$

To estimate the derivative, we'll use this inequality to bound the function strings slopes -

$$\frac{(l-\varepsilon)(x+h)^p - (l+\varepsilon)x^p}{h} \le \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \le \frac{(l+\varepsilon)(x+h)^p - (l-\varepsilon)x^p}{h}$$

The left hand side can be rewritten as

$$ l \frac{(x+h)^p - x^p}{h} - \varepsilon \frac{(x+h)^p + x^p}{h} $$

and the right hand side can be rewritten as

$$ l \frac{(x+h)^p - x^p}{h} + \varepsilon \frac{(x+h)^p + x^p}{h} $$

Here the estimation is a bit more tricky, since the values tends to infinity as $h$ goes to $0$. So we'll do the estimations much more carefully. First, let's fix a constant $\delta > 0$. We can find $h$ such that $$|l * \frac{(x+h)^p - x^p}{h} - lpx^{p-1}| < \delta / 3$$ and also $$ |\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} - f'(x)| < \delta / 3$$ Since this is the analytic derivative compared to the slope defining it. Now, after fixing $h$, we will choose $\varepsilon$ such that $|\varepsilon \frac{(x+h)^p + x^p}{h}| < \delta / 3$, which will in its turn give us $M$ (from the previous limit definition), such that for all $x>M$ we have
$$ lpx^{p-1} - \delta < f'(x) < lpx^{p-1} + \delta $$

we can divide by $px^{p-1}$, say the $\delta$ was arbitrary, and finish with the same claim as above.

Comment: This proves "$\Leftarrow$", but I want "$\Rightarrow$".

Comment: @Hebe thanks for the clarification, I updated my answer and it now proves both directions in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thanks. But there seems some problems in $|\varepsilon\frac{(x+h)^p+x^p}{h}|<\frac{\delta}{3}$ because $M$ you choose is related to $\varepsilon$ at the beginning of the proof. When you want to make $\varepsilon$ small enough to obtain $|\varepsilon\frac{(x+h)^p+x^p}{h}|<\frac{\delta}{3}$, $M$, hence $x$, will become greater. It seems that you do not use the condition that $f'(x)$ is monotonically increasing.

Comment: Moreover, in your proof, $x^p$ can be replaced by any function $g(x)$. I think that $x^p$ will play a special role in the proof.

Comment: Thanks, you are right and my solution is wrong. I didn't take into account the fact that $x$ gets larger as we decrease $\varepsilon$. I will think about it more, but won't delete the answer so maybe someone else can fix it.